# What is the best javascript "time ago" package where I can control formatting?

Tags: javascript, livestamp.js

I want to use a time ago plugin like timeago or livestamp.js but I want to control the formatting to something like this:

1s ago
5s ago
1m25s ago
1h3m ago

Is there a way to do that with either of the above mentioned plugins or is there a better time ago plugin you recommend?

Comment: You might want to try Moment.js

Comment: Try to ask this on softwarerecs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) has the ability to customize the formatting and thresholds for relative time:

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time/

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time-threshold/

Comment: I'd suggest "javascript-time-ago". https://github.com/catamphetamine/javascript-time-ago